# Saving Json in mongodb using spring boot

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I was trying to save json in to mongodb using springboot, but it saved like below

[Saved like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPAVr.jpg)

But i want like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBiWN.jpg)

i was trying to save json with out using getter/setter method since json has 1500+ lines. so trying to add json asis.

Any one please help how can we save raw json

Below is my code

```
`{
    "projectData": {
        "identifier": "40624548-6A0E-44D4-97F7-496175611B62",        
        "projectName": "Sample PC SW Project",
        "companyName": "Brigade Metropolise",
        "street": "Balaji Layout",
        "streetNo": "02",        
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Uncle Bob",        
        "lastName": "Bush",
        "gtcPictureIdentifiers": [
            "a55c7566-b36c-40f1-b21f-d7c0a062353b",
            "bf19459d-74c8-4321-9322-ed9d142f3985"
        ],
        "thermoIdentifiers": [
            "0766B2F6-9B7D-4930-9D40-DE502D96B795",
            "0ADC45C9-70BA-4D91-95BE-EE30F6D104E3"
        ],
        "todoIdentifiers": [],
        "noteIdentifiers": [
            "C9CA3257-E664-4140-99DC-E469550BB3E9"
        ],
        "dataImportedDate": "",
        "thermalImageImportedName": "RB00014Y.JPG",
        "thermalImageImportedDate": null,
        "filesCollection": [
            "RB00024Y",
            "RB00036Y"
        ],
        "inspectorName": ""
    }
}`
```

**Model**

```
@Document(collection = "projectdata")
public class ProjectData {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty()
    private String id;
    
    @JsonProperty(required=true, value="projectData")
    private JsonNode projectData;
    
    public ProjectData(@JsonProperty("projectData") JsonNode projectData)  {
        this.projectData = projectData;
        
    }

    

}
```

**controller**

```
public String postJsonFile(@RequestBody ProjectData projectData, @PathVariable String collection) {     
        projectDataRepository.save(projectData);
        return collection;
    }
```